# In PHP I need to get post data from editarea without it stripping entities

Tags: php, html, forms, html-entities

In my app (just plain PHP 5.5.X) I have an editor into which I want to add html entities amongst the text, for example & but NOT have them converted when I read the POST data in PHP. `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`, as well as calling `file_get_contents("php://input")` and then `parse_str()` all automatically strip the entities out before I get them. I need to store the raw content of the editor's  into a database. Other than rewriting parse_str() myself to avoid this "help" is there any easy way to make this work?

I am creating text in the an html page that I need to keep exactly as entered. If If I enter

```
test &amp;
```

into the textarea  and post the form this is what i get in PHP using $_REQUEST or &_POST

```
test &
```

calling

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

I see

```
editarea=test+%26amp%3B
```

so therefore processing the post data via the normal mechanism replaces `&amp;` with &

This is plain php 5.5.26 I think on ubuntu1404 in a VM via nginx.

Imagine you had written some kind of programming language and wanted PHP to leave your syntax alone. I could convert the area in hex and decode it myself in PHP but that seems really dumb.

Comment: You don't need code, it's a simple question. How to make parse_str not turn &amp; into &

Comment: Yes, we _do_ need code, because PHP doesn’t “strip out” HTML entities on its own. So most likely _you_ are doing something wrong – but since you don’t show us what exactly you are doing, we can’t tell you what that might be.

Comment: @ahwulf `parse_str` would expect `&amp;` to be properly urlencoded to `%26amp%3B`. `$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` don't do *anything* with entities.

Comment: See edits for details. Yes, it does. At least some of them.

Comment: Send test &amp; &#123; you get ` test & {` or raw `editarea=test+%26amp%3B+%26%23123%3B`

Comment: _“this is what i get”_ – and how exactly did you check that? You did _not_ just output the value, and then let the browser _interpret it as HTML again_, right …?

Comment: I put the result into the page and looked at it with Safari's source view. That showed test &. But when I just now looked with Safari's inspector, or Chrome's source view, I see test &amp; ARGH. Even copying the line in the source view that is showing me & returns the correct &amp; but viewing it in source view is showing the interpreted entity.

Comment: So thank you all for your patience. I haven't touched PHP in years.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a way to keep the entities there however you can just use `htmlentities($string);` and convert them back before saving?

Comment: If I could get back the same ones that might work. I don't know that I can count on this though.